# phpDocumentor - Do comment references to other elements need a fully qualified path?

Tags: php, documentation, phpdoc

I couldn't really interpret a clear answer about this from the [documentation](https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/see.html).

When adding a reference to another structural element in a `@see` or `@param` comment, for example, do I always need to use the fully qualified name of the element, even if the two elements are local to each other?

e.g. Object hierarchy

```
Animals
    --- Mammals
        --- Cat
        --- Dog
```

Let's say within the Cat class I want to reference Dog. As they reside within the same namespace, do I need to give the fully qualified path? If it doesn't matter either way, is there a best practice? Should I use the fully qualified path anyway, to remove any ambiguity or misunderstanding by developers reading the code?

```
namespace Animals\Mammals;

class Cat
{

    /**
     * @param Dog $dog An instance of a Dog.
     *
     * OR
     *
     * @param \Animals\Mammals\Dog $dog An instance of a Dog.
     */
    public function foo(Dog $dog)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/types.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't necessary.

[Definition of a ‘Type’](https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/types.html)

> A valid class name seen from the context where this type is mentioned.
>   **Thus this may be either a Fully Qualified Class Name (FQCN) or if
>   present in a namespace a local name.**

phpDocumentor only needs that class type should be documented:

[@param](https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/param.html)

> If the return Type is a class that is documented by phpDocumentor,
>   then a link to that class’ documentation is provided.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a use statement under your namespace declaration, you don't need the fully qualified path.

Also, one more thing. In your example, Animals\Mammals\Dog is in the same namespace as Animals\Mammals\Cat, so you don't need any use statement and can access Dog directly.

Answer (score 0):

Is the selected answer still valid? Because I started a project in 2019 with PHPStorm. Back than the DocBlock created by typing `/**` on methods had no FQCN (e.g. `@param Dog $dog`). Than in 2020 I think there was an PHPStorm update, because suddenly my DocBlocks always containing the full FQCN (`@param \Animals\Mammals\Dog $dog`). It doesn't matter if the class contains a `use Dog;` statement on top!

I didn't change any project-settings, **so my quess is that the newer IDE conciders using the FQCN here is best-practice** nowadays. But I could not find any related sources nor PSRs for it. Does someone knows more?